# ¿Cómo sumar elementos de un string? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, elementos

El resultado debe ser: 123 + 456 + 789 = 1368

```
let numeros = '123,456,789';
let alpha = numeros.split(',');
let gamma = alpha.toString();
let beta  = parseInt(gamma);
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es la relación de _spring_ con la pregunta? Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu código hasta aquí está bien, haces **`split()`** usando la **`,`** como separador y devolviendo un array:

```js
let numeros = '123,456,789';
let alpha = numeros.split(','); // => ["123", "456", "789"]
```

Luego en la siguiente línea de código, estás convirtiendo a **string** nuevamente:

```js
let gamma = alpha.toString(); // => 123,456,789
```

Y hasta ahí ya no sería lo correcto, ya que necesitas sumar los números. Fácilmente puedes sumar los elementos del array (que te devuelve el **`split()`**) utilizando el método [**`reduce()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). Aquí recibo los elementos del array convirtiendo su tipo de dato a numérico usando **`Number()`**, ya que el **`split()`** te devuelve un array con elementos de tipo **string**:

```js
let result = alpha.reduce((acc, val) => acc + Number(val), 0);
```

Código completo:

```js
let numeros = '123,456,789';
let alpha = numeros.split(',');
let result = alpha.reduce((acc, val) => acc + Number(val), 0);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Solamente para complementar con las respuestas que Cris223511.dev y Marce Puente ya hicieron, también puedes llamar a una función externa desde el reduce.

```
let numeros = '123,456,789';
let alpha = numeros.split(',');
let result = alpha.reduce(suma, 0);

function suma(total, num) {
  return total + Number(num);
}
console.log(result);
```

La función se ejecuta por cada elemento no vacío del arreglo

Digamos que esta es la respuesta intermedia entre las anteriores

Answer (score -1):

Presuponiendo que la excelente respuesta de Cris223511.dev está un poco por encima de tu nivel de conocimientos, te dejo una solución más simple (modo cavernícola).

```js
let numeros = '123,456,789';
let alpha = numeros.split( ',' );
let gamma = 0;
for( i in alpha ) {
    gamma += parseInt( alpha[ i ] );
}
console.log( gamma );
```

Después de separar los numeros con **split**, recorres con un **for** el array creado, y le vas sumando a **gamma** el valor numérico de cada posición del array.